# TELEGRAMBOT how to get ChosenInlineResult

Tags: php, telegram-bot

How to get ChosenInlineResult in this result? :
I'm using PHP and here is my send result page

```
 $results = array(
            array(
                "type" => "article",
                "id" => "1",
                "title" => "aaaa",
                "description" => "bbbb",
                "input_message_content" => array(
                    "message_text" => "mt",
                    "parse_mode" => "HTML"
                ),"reply_markup" => array('inline_keyboard' => ($keyboardx))
            )
        );
  $data = array(
        "inline_query_id" => $qid,
        "results" => json_encode($results),
        "cache_time" => 0
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/'.$token.'/answerInlineQuery');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("res.txt",$result,FILE_APPEND);
```

and here I'm saving returned data in res.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to the [BotFather](https://telegram.me/botfather) and set `/setinlinefeedback` to `Enabled` in order to receive `ChosenInlineResult`. Afterwards when a `InlineQueryResult` gets chosen you will receive a message with `ChosenInlineResult`.

```
{
    "update_id" : 123456789,
    "chosen_inline_result" : {
        //[...]
    }
}
```